# Nothing happens when button is clicked

Tags: java, swing, awt, jbutton, actionlistener

I'm writing a program in Java where I'm using JTabbedPane. Each tab is associated with a different panel with labels, textfields and a button. I have used GridBagLayout in the panels. 
I have added an actionlistener to the button, but when I click it nothing happens. 
**EDIT:** I also have other buttons outside the JTabbedPane which works perfectly fine.

I can see that nothing is happening because I do this:

```
public void actionPerformed( ActionEvent e ) { 
    if ( e.getSource() == button ) { 
        System.out.println("blablabla");
    }
```

and nothing is printed out.

Is there any common problems with using buttons and GridBagLayout/JTabbedPane?

**EDIT with SSCCE**

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.WindowAdapter;
import java.awt.event.WindowEvent;
import javax.swing.*;

public class Hjelp extends JFrame { 
    private FlowLayout layout;
    private JButton button1; 
    private JButton button2;
    private JPanel menu, frontpage; 
    private JPanel present, previous, something;

    public Hjelp() {
        layout = new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.CENTER, 10, 20); 
        setLayout(layout);
        setSize(900, 900); 
        setLocationRelativeTo(null); 
        setVisible(true);
        setPanels();
        something = something();
        add(something, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        something.setVisible(false);
        button1 = new JButton("CLICK ME"); 
        add(button1);
        buttonListener();
    }

    private void buttonListener() {
        Buttonlistener listener = new Buttonlistener();
        button1.addActionListener(listener);
        button2.addActionListener(listener);

    }

    private void setPanels() {
        menu = new JPanel(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.CENTER, 10, 0));
        frontpage = new JPanel();
        previous = frontpage;
        present = frontpage;
        add(menu);
    }

    public void visiblePanel() { 
        previous.setVisible(false);
        present.setVisible(true);
    }

    private JPanel something() {
        visiblePanel();
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        panel.setLayout(new GridLayout(1, 1));
        JTabbedPane tabbedPane = new JTabbedPane();

        JComponent panel1 = tab();
        tabbedPane.addTab("Click me", panel1);
        tabbedPane.setMnemonicAt(0, KeyEvent.VK_1);

        tabbedPane.setTabLayoutPolicy(JTabbedPane.SCROLL_TAB_LAYOUT);

        panel.add(tabbedPane);

        return panel;
    }

    private JComponent tab() {
        JPanel panel = new JPanel(false);
        panel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(870, 300));
        panel.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
        GridBagConstraints cs = new GridBagConstraints();
        cs.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
        button2 = new JButton("Click me");
        cs.gridx = 1;
        cs.gridy = 6;
        cs.gridwidth = 1;
        panel.add(button2, cs);
        return panel;
  }

        private class Buttonlistener implements ActionListener { 
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed( ActionEvent e ) { 
            if ( e.getSource() == button1 ) { 
                    present = something; 
                    button1.setVisible(false);
                    something();
                    previous = something;
                }
                else if (e.getSource() == button2) {
                    System.out.println("Blablabla");
                }

        }
    }



    public static void main(String [] args) { 
        final Hjelp vindu = new Hjelp();
        vindu.addWindowListener(
                        new WindowAdapter() {
                            @Override
                            public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) {
                                System.exit(0);
                            }
                        } );
    }

}
```

**SOLVED**

[Solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16472841/1341974)

Comment: Problems with buttons or layout or tabbed pane?  No, they've been part of Java since 1.0/1.1 in 1999.  It's you and your code.  You probably didn't add the Listener class to the button.

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: @Vulcan What is wrong with `==`? This is an identity comparison.

Comment: @duffymo Actually I did add the listener class to the button.

Comment: @Camilla could you post a bit more code ? because I think Marko Topolnik may be right in that an identity comparison could be perfectly good in your case, and the problem may lie elsewhere... Thank you.

Comment: *"Actually I did.."*  Let the SSCCE do the talking, then everything is 'crystal clear'.

Comment: A quick session with a debugger would have answered this question faster than the 52 minutes that have passed since you posted your question.  SO isn't a good place to do this kind of debugging.

Comment: @duffymo I'm kinda new to this, so I don't really know how to use a debugger correctly.

Comment: @AndrewThompson I have now provided a SSCCE.

Comment: @Jalayn see my edit for codeexample. Thank you.

Comment: Interesting problem.  I suspect the reason the 2nd button is not recognized by the listener is because it is being created repeatedly, just have to track down the details..

Answer (score 3):

You don't need the `getSource` check at all—your listener is (hopefully) attached to just one button, so if it was invoked, that already means the button was clicked. Remove the check and unconditionally print your string. If you still don't see anything, *then* you have a problem.

Comment: Actually, my listener is not attached to just one button. I'm sorry if my code was misleading. See my edit. Thank you for your time though!

Comment: So why don't you print something each time your listener is triggered? `getSource`, in my experience, is not a very reliable mechanism. You'd better keep to what everyone else is doing, which is using anonymous classes, each dedicated to its own button.

Answer (score 0):

You may not have attached a handler to the actual button, and therefore the event will never get called.

**Part 1:**

```
        ButtonHandler handler = new ButtonHandler();
        button.addActionListener( handler );
```

**Part 2:**

```
public class ButtonHandler implements ActionListener 
   {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {    

        }
   }
```

**ALSO**: Java GUI can be finicky, rather than using "e.getSource() == button" you could try "button..isFocusOwner()"

Comment: I have attached a handler to the button. See my code here [link](http://pastie.org/7823774)

Comment: @Camilla yes I believe you did (odd way to do it) so try changing the "e.getSource() == button" to "button1.isFocusOwner()" and see what that does.