# For input string: "" when textfields are filled out

Tags: java, actionlistener, numberformatexception

I am writing a program in Java where I got some textfields and a button.

I get a `java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: ""` even though I have filled out all the textfields when running the program.

My code looks something like this:

```
button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        method();
    }
}
            );




public void method() { 
    try { 
        String string1 = textfield1.getText();
        String string2 = textfield2.getText();
        String string3 = textfield3.getText();
        if ( string1.length() == 0 || string2.length() == 0 || string3.length() == 0) { 
            System.out.println("fill in the required text fields");
            return;
        } 
        int number = Integer.parseInt(textfield3.getText());
        //do something
    }
    catch ( NumberFormatException e ) { 
        System.out.println("Wrong format");
    }
}
```

**EDIT:**

[See more code here](http://pastie.org/7824509)

Comment: You assign `textfield3.getText();` to `string3`. Might as well use it! Also, debug your code. It will tell you where you're going wrong. And after looking at the code you've supplied, I can't see anything wrong. Now it's time to iron out some of the silly mistakes. Are you sure `textfield3` is the correct field?

Comment: My guess is that your code looks like this, but not exactly. And the bug is probably in the "not exactly" part. Post an SSCCE that reproduces the problem.

Comment: Try using String#trim().length(). Add in some System.outs to test the values of the text fields and try debugging the code

Comment: I don't think the error is in method, because you catch the exception, can you post more code or this is the only time you convert String to numbers in your code ?

Comment: @JBNizet I've added a link to my code now.

Comment: @ChrisCooney I've added a link to my code now.

Comment: @RicardoCacheira I've added a link to my code now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have tested your program a little bit and you have a problem with the text field, because of the creation of your panel and switching which one is active.

In the constructor you call the something() method which creates the JTextField. When the button is clicked you call again something() and a new JTextField is generated which you also add to the panel.

So you have two JTextFields on the GUI at the exact same position but only a reference to one of them (the last one created).

When you click the button which will call method(). The hidden TextField is asked for his text (this is how it works on my pc) and this is always empty because I can only write into the one I see.

An easy fix to this is to change the method actionPerformed:

```
@Override
public void actionPerformed( ActionEvent e ) {
    if ( e.getSource() == button1 ) {
        present = something;
        button1.setVisible(false);
        //something();
        visiblePanel();
        previous = something;
    }

}
```

So I avoid the new creation of the JTextField but visiblePanel() ensures the TextField and second button are shown.

After this change I can type in "sadda" press the button and see the output "Numberformatexception". When I type in a number I see nothing so the formatting works.